# MYSQL insert after sub query with count

Tags: mysql, insert, subquery

I'm trying to INSERT some data into a table but only when the subquery COUNT is > 0.

This is what I have so far.

```
INSERT INTO users_friends (userId, friendId) VALUES (77, 100) 
WHERE 
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE email = 'a@g.com') > 0
```

Both queries work independently FYI.

This should be a simple fix hopefully. Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SQLFiddle demo if there are records 'a@g.com'](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b15c/1)

[SQLFiddle demo if there are NOT records 'a@g.com'](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f5b2b/1)

```
INSERT INTO users_friends (userId, friendId) 
SELECT 77, 100 
FROM users WHERE email = 'a@g.com' LIMIT 1;
```

Another way would be:

```
INSERT INTO users_friends (userId, friendId) 
SELECT 77, 100 
FROM dual
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = 'a@g.com' ) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this::

```
INSERT INTO users_friends (userId, friendId) 
(SELECT 77, 100  FROM users GROUP BY email HAVING email= 'a@g.com' and count(id)>0)
```

Comment: But in this case if count for example = 4 then 4 records (77, 100) will be inserted into table.

Comment: That's an awesome way around it! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO users_friends (userId, friendId) 
SELECT 77, 100 FROM users WHERE email = 'a@g.com'
GROUP BY email
HAVING COUNT(id) > 0
```