# MYSQL - SELECT AS alias to be used in subquery

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

I want to be able to use one of the items I am selecting further down in my sub query.
As you can see in this example I have set the "variable" in question as 100 but in reality this is going to be a dynamic number so I will need to be able to access it in the subquery.

```
INSERT INTO users_friends (userId, friendId) 
SELECT 77, id as noob
FROM users WHERE email = 'a@g.com' 
AND
NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users_friends
WHERE userId = 77 and friendId = noob)
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Can you provide more info with regard to the table structure and sample? And what your desired result is. A prima vista I would think that this is only possible if you like to do this with PHP or another language to insert a dynamic variable. If the dynamic number is not inside a table and there is no way for MySQL to generate it, you will need another intermediary programming language to do this.

Comment: why haven't you asked more info in you previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833940/mysql-insert-after-sub-query-with-count

Comment: That question has been answered and this is a completely different question. I don't think any of that information is necessary, you can see what the desired result is from reading the above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO users_friends (userId, friendId) 
SELECT 77, id 
FROM users WHERE email = 'a@g.com' 
AND
NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users_friends
WHERE userId = 77 and friendId = (SELECT id 
FROM users WHERE email = 'a@g.com'))
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: the sub query in the last part finds what the id is I need to check against. Don't know why this took me so long to realise!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure I understand your question, but NOT EXISTS works just like LEFT JOIN and IS NULL.  So I think this will work:

```
SELECT 77, @noob
FROM users u
  JOIN (SELECT @noob:= 100) r
  LEFT JOIN users_friends uf on u.userid = uf.userid and uf.friendid = @noob
WHERE email = 'a@g.com' 
  AND uf.userid IS NULL
```

And here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2ede/1).

Comment: Hey. Sorry man it's hard to explain but I basically need to be able to use that second noob in a later subquery. Is there any way of doing so. This suggestion doesn't work for the overall purpose of the query.

Comment: @Andre -- I do not think you can use variables like this in subqueries -- depends on your exact needs.  Maybe something like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2ede/8 -- then you can access the new column noob.  Best of luck.

Comment: is it not possible to set it as a variable in any way after it has been assigned to a number? Seems like there should be an easy way to do it :z

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

I would recommend changing your table structure.

```
    CREATE TABLE users_friends(
userid int, 
friendid int,
primary key (userid, friendid)
);

CREATE TABLE users (
 userid int primary key, 
 email varchar(100), 
 name VARCHAR (100),
 index (email,name)
);


INSERT INTO users VALUES (1, 'a@g.com', 'noob'), (2,'b@g.com', 'Joe');


INSERT INTO users_friends (userId, friendId) 
VALUES (2, (SELECT userId 
FROM users 
WHERE email = 'a@g.com' 
AND name = "noob"
AND NOT exists (SELECT * FROM users_friends as uf 
            JOIN users as u 
            ON u.userid = uf.userid 
            where uf.friendid = 2 AND name = "noob"            
           )
           ) 
       );
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/facfc6/1)

Try this:

```
    <?php

    function select_query ($userid,$friendname, $email){
    $host = "host";
    $user = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $database = "database name";

    // open connection to databse
    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
            IF (!$link){
                echo ("Unable to connect to database!");
            }
            ELSE {
               //Is someone registered at other conference from table registration
               $query = "    INSERT INTO users_friends (userId, friendId) 
VALUES (".$userId.", (SELECT userId 
FROM users 
WHERE email = '".$email."' 
AND name = '".$friendname."'
AND NOT exists (SELECT * FROM users_friends as uf 
            JOIN users as u 
            ON u.userid = uf.userid 
            where uf.friendid = ".$userId." AND name = '"$friendname"'            
           )
           ) 
       )"; 
               $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
               return $query;
               return $result;
            }
            mysqli_close($link);
    }

    echo select_query(1,noob,'a@g.com');
   ?>
```

Like I mentioned above I not sure what you mean. If you mean dynamic in the sense that you can change the value of the variable this might help. In your previous posts you used PHP. So, my guess is that your are using PHP.

Comment: The thing is I do not know the friend ID prior to pulling the query. I'm getting that in teh select part which I then nee to use in the sub query. Thanks though.

Comment: @Andre a couple of questions do you know the userID? Is there a column that contains the name from the friend? Is this the friends name inside the friendID column?

Comment: hey, no there is no name within the friend column. I do know the user id though,

Comment: Strange in Fiddle it works. So, have altered your data structure in you mysql database? Try to do this: `INSERT INTO users_friends VALUES (2,1);` and then the query. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b035

Comment: @Andre most important change was this: `primary key (userid, friendid)` to table users_friends. It creates a composite key for your table_friends. If you already have a primary key you could add this `unique(userid, friendid)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think the safest approach is to define these in a subquery.  I typically give this the alias of const:

```
INSERT INTO users_friends (userId, friendId) 
    SELECT const.userId, const.noob
    FROM users cross join
         (select 77 as userId, 100 as noob) const
    WHERE email = 'a@g.com' AND
          NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM users_friends
                      WHERE userId = const.userId and friendId = const.noob
                     )
    LIMIT 1
```

I am concerned about SGeddes's approach, because it relies on the correct evaluation of variables outside the scope of the query.  This might work in this case, but I prefer a solution where the query does not rely on outside variables.  By the way, this should also work in any database, and is not MySQL-specific.

Comment: Hey. This work however the 100 is just there to fill a variable that I don't know until the query is called. So I need to use the beginning part of the query like so...  INSERT INTO users_friends (userId, friendId) 
(SELECT 77, id  FROM users WHERE email = 'c@c.com')

Comment: INSERT INTO users_friends (userId, friendId) 
SELECT 77, id 
FROM users WHERE email = 'a@g.com' 
AND
NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users_friends
WHERE userId = 77 and friendId = (SELECT id 
FROM users WHERE email = 'a@g.com'))
LIMIT 1